# Is there an event to handle Successful creation of record when event force:createRecord is used

Tags: lightning-aura-components, record, create-records, lightning-events, callback

I am creating custom object records using standard salesforce record creation feature by firing the *event* **force:createRecord** from my custom component.

After saving the record, Page navigates to standard record view.
But I want to handle the successful case(event) instead and perform reloadData/refreshView on my custom component.

Whereas for *Record Edit* -  "force:recordSaveSuccess" *Event* is working when using *Component* **force:recordEdit** (instead of force:editRecord event). But I could find no such component for *Create Record*.

---

**Is there any way we can handle successful case (record saved) or override Save or set callback??**

```
createRecord : function (component, event, helper) {
    var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
    createRecordEvent.setParams({
        "entityApiName": "MyCustomObject__c"
    });
    createRecordEvent.fire();
},
```

Thanks for your time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such event available in **force:createRecord**

If you want to achieve this you need to create your custom lightning component which will do the similar functionality and then you can handle the behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Probably I will leave this as is. This is a temporary component and we would like to go with standard feature at this moment, will create custom component when required.

Comment: Mark this is as correct answer, if this helped you